# How we can get response from google Calendar api

Tags: java, api, calendar

I am receiving calendar events on my server by calling the Google Calendar API,
while an event is changed or added to the calendar again I need to call Google calender api.
But I want that we don't need to call calendar api every time. If there is a change, I get a response from Google on my server
is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can request push notifications, you need to set up a notification channel for each resource you want to watch.

To use push notifications, you need to do two things:

1. Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
2. Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.

For more information you can refer here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push